# How to make MySQL produce an error if value not specified on NOT NULL Columns?

Tags: mysql, null

Let's assume that I have a NOT NULL column in a table,

How can I make MySQL to produce an error if such statement is used?

```
INSERT INTO tableName () VALUES ();
```

Thank you.

Comment: What values does it insert? Does the column have a default value set?

Comment: It inserts 0 + Warning.

Comment: Will it let you set the default to NULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To set a column to not null use this syntax :**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name [data type] NOT NULL;
```

If you column is declared `not null` an error will be produced !! 

If you want a customized error msg then you need to create trigger action ! 
**Here is a trigger that can help you :**

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER trgBEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
declare msg varchar(255);
      IF (NEW.col1IS NULL ) THEN
           set msg = concat('MyTriggerError: Trying to insert a null value );
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
      ELSE
            SET NEW.col1= NEW.col1);
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The column is NOT NULL already + verified,
but it still doesn't produce an error, but fills 0 on the value + warning.

Comment: Then what is your question ? it does not throw an error ?

Comment: My question is "How to make MySQL produce an error, when inserting a row to a table containing NOT NULL column, when not specifiying a value to that column like in "INSERT INTO tableName () VALUES ()".

Is there a way without a trigger?

Comment: try : insert into tbl values (null);

Comment: see here mysql is kind of bad with check constraints http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html  -- i would go for triggers to keep my logic in order

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but it might help someone.

You can set the SQL mode, either in the configuration file or at runtime for current session.
To produce the error you need to enable strict sql mode with:
`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';` or `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';`
[Here is a link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html) for more information on sql modes.

Answer (score -1):

> How to make MySQL produce an error, when inserting a row to a table containing `NOT NULL` column, when not specifying a value to that column like in "`INSERT INTO tableName () VALUES()`".
>
> Is there a way without a trigger?

This is possible without a trigger only when you define no `default` when defining a column. Also the same is applicable for `alter ... column ...`

**Example 1**:

```
create table ck_nn( i int not null );
insert into ck_nn values();
```

The above `insert` throws an error as no default is defined on the column.
Message can be something like `Field 'i' doesn't have a default value`.

**Example 2**:

```
create table ck_nn2( i2 int not null default 999 );
insert into ck_nn2 values();
```

The above `insert` won't throw any error as default value is defined on the column.

```
select * from ck_nn2;

+-----+
|  i2 |
+-----+
| 999 |
+-----+
```

**Example** @ [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a340/2)

Comment: @Up_One: Point is OP's question. *How can I make MySQL to produce an error if such statement is used?*